# Attaching a file to an email with PHP

Tags: php, wamp

I have a function that is supposed to be attaching a file to an outgoing email.   For some reason it is only sending blank files.

Can someone help?  I have verified that the files themselves are being uploaded correctly, and are at the exact location needed for this function to work.  Only .pdf, .doc, and .docx are allowed

Also, this is on a Windows Server...  (I know, I know...YUCK!)

Here is the function:

```
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {
    $file = str_replace('/','\\',$path.$filename);
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "rb");
    $contenta = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($contenta));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $name = basename($file);
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
        return true; // or use booleans here
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is the code using this:

```
//resume
$errors="";
$dbDir="/candidate-resources/files/temp/";
$baseDir=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$dbDir;
$validTypes=array(".doc",".pdf",".docx");
$filesToAdd=array();
$atLeastOne=false;
$valid=false;
$qs="";
if(count($_FILES)>0){
    foreach($_FILES as $k=>$v){
        if($v['size']>0){
            $ext=substr($v['name'],strrpos($v['name'],"."));
            if(!in_array($ext,$validTypes)){
                $errors='Only ".doc", ".docx", and ".pdf" files can be uploaded. "'.$ext.'" is not a valid file type.';
            }
        }
    }
}
$requireds=array("name","email","message");
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v){//check for injection and spammers
    if(preg_match("/(%0A|%0D|\\n+|\\r+)(content-type:|to:|cc:|bcc:)/i",$v) || strpos($v,"http://")!==false || strpos($v,"www.")!==false){
        $errors="HTML, website addresses, and scripting code are not allowed in any field.  Please check your entries and try again.";
    }
    $post[$k]=strip_tags(trim(htmlentities($v)));
}
unset($_POST);
foreach($requireds as $r){
    if(!strlen(trim($post[$r]))){
        $errors.="<li>".ucwords($r)."</li>";
    }
}
if(strlen(trim($errors))){
    $errors="These fields were left blank.  Please fix and resubmit.<ul>".$errors."</ul>";
}
else{
    if(ereg("([[:alnum:]\.\-]+)(\@[[:alnum:]\.\-]+\.+)",$post['email'])!=true){
        $errors="<p>You must enter a valid email address.</p>";
    }
    else{
        $filename = '';
        $ext = '';
        // upload the file, then attach it to the email, then delete it
        foreach($_FILES as $k=>$v){
            if($v['size']!=0){
                $atLeastOne=true;
                $ext=substr($v['name'],strrpos($v['name'],"."));                
                move_uploaded_file($v['tmp_name'], $baseDir . "/" . $v['name']);
                $filename = $v['name'];
            }
        }
        $to = 'avalid@emailaddress';
        $subject="Contact Form";
        $headers="From: ".$post["name"]." <".$post["email"].">\r\nReply-To: ".$post["email"]."\r\n";
        $message=$subject."\r\n=================================================\r\n\r\n";
        foreach($post as $k=>$v) {
            if(strlen(trim($v))){
                $message.=ucwords(str_replace("_"," ",$k)).": {$v}\r\n";
            }
        }
        if(strlen($filename) > 0) {
            mail_attachment($filename, $baseDir, $to, $post["email"], $post["name"], $post["email"], $subject, $message);
            //now delete the temp file
            if (file_exists(str_replace('/','\\',$baseDir.$filename))) { 
                unlink(str_replace('/','\\',$baseDir.$filename)); // delete it here only if it exists
            }
        }else{
            mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
        }
        $errors="true";
    }
}
```

please forgive...  I just inherited this code (that is: #1 7 years old, #2 now they wanted the ability to attach a file to this email)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my function around some, and this works:

```
function mail_attachment($from, $fromname, $to, $subj, $text, $filename){
    $f         = fopen($filename,"rb"); 
    $un        = strtoupper(uniqid(time())); 
    $head      = "From: $fromname <$from>\n"; 
    $head     .= "To: $to\n"; 
    $head     .= "Subject: $subj\n"; 
    $head     .= "X-Mailer: PHPMail Tool\n"; 
    $head     .= "Reply-To: $from\n"; 
    $head     .= "Mime-Version: 1.0\n"; 
    $head     .= "Content-Type:multipart/mixed;"; 
    $head     .= "boundary=\"----------".$un."\"\n\n"; 
    $zag       = "------------".$un."\nContent-Type:text/html;\n"; 
    $zag      .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n$text\n\n"; 
    $zag      .= "------------".$un."\n"; 
    $zag      .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream;"; 
    $zag      .= "name=\"".basename($filename)."\"\n"; 
    $zag      .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\n"; 
    $zag      .= "Content-Disposition:attachment;"; 
    $zag      .= "filename=\"".basename($filename)."\"\n\n"; 
    $zag      .= chunk_split(base64_encode(fread($f, filesize($filename))))."\n";
    return @mail("$to", "$subj", $zag, $head);
}
```

(without the need for a 3rd party include)

Answer (score 7):

Start using [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) ([documentation](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/introduction.html)) or [PhpMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/), your life will be easier...

## Swiftmailer example:

```
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
    ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
    ->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))
    ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
    ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('my-document.pdf'));
$mailer->send($message);
```

## PhpMailer example :

```
$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");
$mail->AddAddress("whoto@otherdomain.com", "John Doe");
$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";
$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment
if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

I prefer Swiftmailer, but you select you best choice ;-)

Comment: I agree.  Definately useful, however, I do not have the option of including any 3rd party libraries.  Sorry.  Gave you a plus though